# systemd service file: including dynamic timestamp in log filenames defined in StandardOutput= and StandardError=

Tags: systemd, logs, services, timestamps, systemd-unit

I've created a systemd service unit file, and since systemd version 240+, we can just set the STDOUT + STDERR outputs to go directly into files, like this:

```
StandardOutput=append:/tmp/my-service.log
StandardError=append:/tmp/my-service.log
```

Is there a way for me to add in the current timestamp of when the service was started into these filenames?

e.g. instead of `/tmp/my-service.log`, each time the service starts, it's something like: `/tmp/my-service.2022-07-07_114035.log`

If it was similar to a shell script, I could do something like:

```
StandardOutput=append:/tmp/my-service.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S).log
StandardError=append:/tmp/my-service.$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S).log
```

...but that doesn't work in systemd config files.

Comment: Tried calling `/bin/date`?

Comment: @stoney Well yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to do, as shown under "If it was similar to a shell script, I could do something like:".    I'm asking how to dynamically call it inside a systemd config file (every time the service restarts) and set it in the `StandardOutput=` and `StandardError=` fields?

Comment: I meant calling it with full path

Comment: @stoney Ah ok.  Yeah that doesn't work either.  Systemd unit files don't support `$()` in the first place.